# Не могу добавлять объекты в контроллер через this

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, coffeescript

```
/app/assets/javascripts/components/taskList.coffee
angular.module('app').component 'taskList',
  templateUrl: 'taskList.html'
  controller: 'TaskCtrl'
  bindings:
    project: '='

/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/comment.coffee
angular.module('app').controller 'TaskCtrl', [ '$scope', 'TaskResource' , ($scope, TaskResource) ->
  console.log this.project # есть
  this.something_this = "something"
  $scope.something_scope = "something"
]

/app/assets/javascripts/templates/projectList.html.slim
task-list [project="project"]

/app/assets/javascripts/templates/taskList.html.slim
.task-controller
  p {{ $ctrl.project.id }} // есть
  p {{ $ctrl.something_this }} //пусто, почему?
  p {{ something_scope }} // есть
```

Такая же проблема сохраняется, если присоединять контроллер к view напрямую через ng-controller

Comment: можешь сделать [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть?

Comment: @Grundy, [сделал](http://jsbin.com/kixuruwaci/edit?html,js,output), видимо такое происходит только у меня на [машине](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/todolist), не могу понять почему

Comment: Значит нужно добавлять пример больше кода из варианта где не работает. Возможно, что-то может переписывать это поле, либо просмотр происходит в другом компоненте

Comment: @Grundy, я понял, написал в ответе, это просто лол, можете объяснить? раньше же такого не было

Comment: а `return` к какой функции относится?

Comment: @Grundy, получается `return this.setDeadline = func....`

Comment: странно как-то.

Comment: @Grundy Вот именно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# правильный вариант
angular.module('app').controller 'TaskCtrl', [ '$scope', 'TaskResource'
    , ($scope, TaskResource) ->

  console.log this.project
  this.something_this = "something"
  $scope.something_scope = "something"

  this.setDeadline = (task, date) -> # вот здесь будет вставлен return this.setDeadline, что все и ломает, почему?
    TaskResource.deadline({ id: task.id }, { deadline: date }).$promise.then (response) ->
      task.deadline = response.deadline
    .catch (response) ->
      task.deadline = null

  return # раньше return не было
]
```